# How to calculate a sum of an area-weighted polygons within a polygon in R?

Tags: r, r-sf

I have blocks of census data (shapefile with the column of interest being pop20) and polygons of areas of interest (shapefile with the column of interest being site).  I am trying to get a sum of the population within each of the areas of interest (see example of one area of interest and the census blocks below).  I don't know how to join the population estimates (column: pop20) to the areas of interest and account for polygons that are only partially within the areas of interest.

Hence I am interested in the following:

1. what is the population within each census block within each area of interest, accounting for some blocks only being partial inside (so if 1/2 the block is within the area of interest, assume the population is 1/2 of the value in pop20).
2. Then what is the sum of all the blocks within the area of interest weighing the blocks that are only partially within the area of interest from part 1.

[image: area of interest in blue and census blocks in pink with grey boarders]

I have essentially imported by shapefiles using the sf package but then I don't know what to do (do I use st_intersection or st_join or something else)?

```
pop<-st_read("...\\pop_census2020_prj.shp")
buff<-st_read("...\\trap_mcpbuff_prj.shp")
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I wrote a blog post a while back that does a walkthrough of a possible approach; you may find it interesting https://www.jla-data.net/eng/spatial-aggregation/